# MySQL:How much aprox disk space required for bin_log of the 80GB of DB?

Tags: mysql

I had total 80GB of database in MySQL server,and there is huge amount of trasaction are happend on daily basis,I need to be enable a bin_log so I required a recommendation how much disk space is reqired for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way, it does not matter since you should purge the binlogs.  But first, there are two questions -- why do you have the binlog, and are you using SBR or RBR?

If the binlog is for incremental backups, then you need it (them) to be big enough to last until you take the next backup.  This might be a few GB per day for a "busy" system.

If you have Slave(s) that are replicating via the binlog, then it depends on how long before you purge the binlogs.  I like to set expire_logs_days = 7 or 14.  So, now I am looking at 10s of GB.

Statement Based Replication (SBR) needs room for the text of each write and DDL statement, plus some overhead.  You might be able to get a crude estimate of the binlog growth from knowing that.

Row Based Replication (RBR) is likely to be bulkier, and I don't have a good estimate.

You should not plan on keeping the binlogs forever.

The size of the dataset is mostly irrelevant; it's all about how often things are changing.

Comment: Thanx Rick James.I required the binlog for the incremental backup.

Comment: One more thing if I set the variable expire_logs_days=7 then It required to set the binlogpurge job or it will be purged automatically after 7 days.

Comment: @RkSingh Assuming MySQL does not have a bug (something that happened long time ago), they will be automatically purged, but you may need to tune also the `max_binlog_size`, as MySQL will not delete files that are currently in use by the master.

Comment: @RickJames a very loose estimation of RBR is 2x the size of an image of the rows modified + overhead, as it basically stores the old and the new versions of each row modified with its default configuration.